# How to reset to any of the previous commit in android studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I made some commits to git from android studio. Now I want to reset to one of the committed version. How can I do that within android studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Revert Git repo to a previous commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-git-repo-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

open terminal in android studio :

You can do this by following two commands:

```
git reset --hard [previous Commit SHA id here]
git push origin [branch Name] -f
```

It will remove your previous git commit.

If you want to keep your changes you can also use:

```
git reset --soft [previous Commit SHA id here]
```

Then it will save your changes.

For more details  [How do you undo the last commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-you-undo-the-last-commit)

Answer (score 18):

At last I have found the solution.

1. Go to **VCS -> Git -> Show History**[image]
2. From **Log**, right click on the required committed version and select **Reset Current Branch to Here**.[image]
3. Select **Hard** and click on **Reset** button.